# Angular 2: Get model name inside [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular

I'm having a hard time finding a way to extract the model name set in [(ngModel)].

```
[(ngModel)]="subjectPropertyInformation.siteSize"
```

I don't need the value of this one but the model name which is the string "subjectPropertyInformation.siteSize". I'm planning to pass this string on (change) directive.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this something like use single way binding.

```
 <input [ngModel]="subjectPropertyInformation.siteSize" 
        (change)="onChange($event)">
```